# site load more time in url rewrite using .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi I am new to url rewrite  help in this process.

Actually I want to rewrite my url from :

`http://abcd.com/merchant.php?store=2&area=323&storename=Vendor-2`

to

`http://abcd.com/Vendor-2`

But it's not working. When I click on href target that time it is loading. Below is my `.htaccess`  file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /merchant\.php?store=1&area=132&storename=$1 [L]
```

Above file is my `.htaccess` file but it's not working.

Can somebody give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
# This should match when storename contains [a-zA-Z0-9_-]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} storename=([\w-]+)
RewriteRule merchant.php /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks bosss.it's working fine but it's show 404 page                                                         `Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[^\ ]+
 RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L] #remove query string

 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} storename=([\w-]+)
 RewriteRule ^merchant.php /%1.html [R=301,L]

 ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`    above htacess file is modified file